# Instagram real API

Tags: node.js, instagram

I'm trying to set up a real time website that retrieves a specific hashtag from Instagram. My website uses Node.js, however, each time i try to run the server, i get this answer from the server node.js command line:

OAuthParameterException occurred: The client_id provided is invalid and does not
 match a valid application. in _request
OAuthParameterException occurred: Missing client_id or access_token URL paramete
r. in _request

What is wrong with my configuration ?

is it something linked with my callback url ? what should i put in there ? thank you

Comment: What is your configuration ?

Comment: http://pastie.org/8670123

Comment: i might have an issue with my callback_url, i have pushed my node.js to heroku with the node, uploaded everything then in my website, but i cannot understand what to put in REDIRECT URI for instagram.

Answer (score 0):

If we can see your configuration it would help. 
However, using my handy crystal ball, I would hazard a guess that the client (your webserver) does not have a current OAuth token from Instagram and while trying to get it, cannot find a valid user ID.

The motherload of all information on node.js OAuth can be found by reading the documentation for the node.js passport module - https://npmjs.org/package/passport

Comment: is it not something linkend with me doing something wrong with the Redirect URL (callback url) ?? i've indicated this url as my website index.html file